# Jquery and Extjs Simplest Tutorial

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I want link to tutorial for JQuery and ExtJs which will cover following contents or Topics

Note: PLease do not provide me link of their sites i know them.

1. How to setup both of the packages.

It is required as its essential.

2. How to access a DIV element
3. How to get all the elements in a div like checkboxes, radio buttons, div etc
4. How to position a DIV with  respect another DIV (It Sholud be cross browser compliant)

etc

PLease  do let me know

Comment: @mandrex1: Maybe you should rephrase the line "Note: PLease do not provide me link of their sites i know them." because if you "know" them you would not ask the question.

Comment: It bothers me when people actually answer questions like this.  Lazy is right.

Comment: There are 3 over smart people over here: 
Obalix, bmoeskau and uroc

and special thx to Aaron Conran and Obalix :))))

Comment: @mandrex1: Your question is not very precise and you can learn the basic information within a few hours. Instead you ask a question that shows that you not willing to invest time to learn. Now some people citicizing your style and still are prepared to spend time answering your question. Then you come back and call them "overly smart". This is not a very appropriate to thank people for the help they provided to you. At least where I am from this is considered bad manners ... sorry.

Comment: @mandrex1: You need to come up with very specific question in this forum. The more specific your question is, the faster you'll get an answer. I don't know about JQuery, but ExtJs has relatively large collection of easy-to-understand examples, and a forum - though not as responsive as stackoverflow - still filled with pointers. Kind of Conran to take his time to answer your question - I assume he normally uses his time to develop ExtJs.

Answer (score 4):

**Ext JS**

Take a look at the Ext Core Manual
http://www.extjs.com/products/extcore/manual/

> How to setup both of the packages.

1. Download Ext Core
2. Link ext-core-debug.js via a script tag (

Check out the Overview section of the manual.

> How to access a DIV element

```
var div = Ext.get('idOfDiv');
```

Check out the Element -> Getting Elements section of the manual.

> How to get all the elements in a div
>   like checkboxes, radio buttons, div
>   etc

Using the above div reference

```
var inputs = div.select('input');
```

Check out DomQuery and Composite Elements section of the Core Manual

> How to position a DIV with respect
>   another DIV (It Sholud be cross
>   browser compliant)

You can use the positioning methods of Ext.Element, getXY, getLeft, getTop, etc and the corresponding setXY, setLeft, setTop, etc

Check out Element -> Positioning in the Ext Core Manual

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a script directory on your web project.
2. Download the packages and extract the files in your script directory.
3. Add the appropriate script tags for each package (note that you have to use exJs' support for JQuery, otherwise you would have two methods for accessing the elements of your page). The tutorial [Basic Page Setup](http://www.extjs.com/learn/Tutorial:Basic_Page_Setup) describes what you need to do - see additional information below!
4. Try to follow some of the tutorials. It would take too long to describe what you have to do to achieve this or that (which we don't even know). Studying the tutorials and reproducing some of the results should set you back half a day or a day. (Exjs tutorials: http://www.extjs.com/learn/Tutorials and http://www.extjs.com/learn/Main_Page, JQuery tutorials: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials).

**Note for step 3:**
When following the [Basic Page Setup](http://www.extjs.com/learn/Tutorial:Basic_Page_Setup) tutorial, prefix all ext/ directories with the path to your script directory, e.g. "/myScriptDir/" (used from here on to represent your script directory). Additionally replace

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myScriptDir/ext/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myScriptDir/jquery-jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></Script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myScriptDir/ext/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
```

For accessing the elements on you page you can use [JQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), e.g.

1. `var divs = $('div'); // gets the div elements in the document`
2. `var inputs = $('div input'); // gets the input elements inside a div in the document`

And just at the end some friendly advice: To solve a problem you have to be prepared to learn. Never assume that the solution will be presented as a gift.

Answer (score -1):

It is obvious that Mandrex1's primary language is not English.  What he was trying to ask are the links to any information on how to use DIV in an integrated jquery and extjs scenario.  He was also requesting everyone not to bother posting links on setting up an integrated jquery and extjs because he already knew how to do it.

He is not lazy.  In fact, he is quite resourceful because he was asking where to find those information rather than asking for the actual solution to his problem.